# Easy way to transfer schema from SQL Server database to SQL Server CE database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

I have a project that currently uses a SQL Server database on the shared hosting server that I pay for monthly. I want to migrate my schema from there to a new SQL Server CE database in my solution. Is there an easy way to do this?

I can't see a way to do this without manually re-creating the entire thing. It's a decently sized schema, but it's not very complicated. It's just tables with some foreign keys here and there, nothing fancy.

Anyone know how to migrate down from a regular SQL Server database to a SQL Server CE database?

Comment: See this blog post: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2012/02/migrating-databases-between-sql-server.html

Comment: Your post looks like it offers what I want afterall, but I am trying to port my sql server db to my sql server ce db and my SQL server instance is hosted on a shared hosting server at seaweed.arvixe.com so I don't have the permissions I would have if I owned the server. When I put in all my connection data and do test connection it is successful, but when I click OK I get this error: http://www.codetunnel.com/content/images/sqlceimport.jpg

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/lqtr1CCni6PN I took a screencast to show you what I am doing. Maybe you can help.

Comment: Just so you know, I managed to get it working. I was able to generate a schema creation script from arvixe and then use that to create the database locally. Then I used your tool to connect to the local DB instead of the arvixe server. I was able to generate the sqlce script beautifully. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please feel free to mark my answer...

Comment: Patience. Good things come to those who wait. I always mark my answers :) I just don't like to mark them prematurely.

Answer (score 3):

http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/

It can script SQL Server databases for running on CE.

Comment: Does this work with SQL Compact 4.0? The installers all say 3.5.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm dumb. http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/ for VS 2010 and CE 4 support.

Comment: I installed this. While cool and useful, it does not support importing data from another database into my SQL CE database. It does scripting of objects from my CE database for other databases, but not the other way around.

Comment: 3.5 is the version number, all my tools support 3.5 and 4.0

Comment: I see, I did not realize that I could click the root node to do an import. However, see my comment on your answer below for my newest issue :P